# cannot change default email address in PHP

Tags: php, cpanel

So I created new email from my cpanel and I'm trying to use it for registration verification.
I tried editing "php.ini" it didn't work then I used this code and its still not working its sending message from default email.

```
ini_set('SMTP', "mail.website.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","25");
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'verify@website.com');
```

sorry I'm new to web development and i have no idea what im doing wrong

Comment: could you supply the error text? Since that might be what is going wrong ;).

Comment: im not getting any error text...

Comment: are you trying  to send mail using smtp

Comment: that default is stored *somewhere*... find it.

Comment: please, add cpanel to tags.

Comment: im sending msg with "mail()" from php

Comment: i found it in php.ini but when i change it it still continues using default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sendmail_from setting can be ignored under various circumstances. Try sending the address with each individual email manually:

```
mail('receiver@domain.com', 'Subject', 'Text', 'From: verify@website.com');
```